# Query an object array using linq

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to know how can I query an array of objects. For example I have an array object like CarList. So CarList[0] would return me the object Car. Car has properties Model and Make. Now, I want to use linq to query the array CarList to get the Make of a Car whose Model is say "bmw". I tried the following

```
var carMake = from item in CarList where item .Model == "bmw" select s.Make;
```

I get the error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type CarList[]

I cannot change CarList from array to something like List<> since CarList is retured to me as array from a webservice.

How can this be solved?

Comment: shouldn't you select item.Make?

Comment: All, what's the reason to up-vote twice a question generated by a typo in the code? changing s into item and removing space before .Model is the only solution he needed.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

to the top of your file.

And then:

```
Car[] carList = ...
var carMake = 
    from item in carList
    where item.Model == "bmw" 
    select item.Make;
```

or if you prefer the fluent syntax:

```
var carMake = carList
    .Where(item => item.Model == "bmw")
    .Select(item => item.Make);
```

Things to pay attention to:

- The usage of `item.Make` in the `select` clause instead if `s.Make` as in your code.
- You have a whitespace between `item` and `.Model` in your `where` clause