# dataGridView Row Filteration using NAV web services

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, datagridview, navision

I am trying to create a filterable data view of data which I get it through a web service in NAV 2009.

I created a windows form and pulled the essential data from a NAV page, created an array and showed in a dataGridView using web services.

What I need now, is to filter by row the data which I have in my dataGridView.

My code would be

```
private void LoadDataGrid()
    {

        WS_GLEntry_Service GLEntryService = new WS_GLEntry_Service();
        GLEntryService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        WS_GLEntry[] Entries = GLEntryService.ReadMultiple(null,null,0);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Entries;

        (dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

But in the last line of my code which contains dataGridViewFields is not in the context. If I want to modify my coding how should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to fetch filtered data or filter fetched data?

Comment: Either way is fine, better if I can fetch filtered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read filtered data why don't you use first parameter `filterArray` of `ReadMultiple` function which [reads a filtered set of records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477110.aspx)

```
List<Customer_Filter> filterArray = new List<Customer_Filter>();
Customer_Filter nameFilter = new Customer_Filter();
nameFilter.Field = Customer_Fields.Name;
nameFilter.Criteria = "S*";
filterArray.Add(nameFilter);
Customer[] custList = service.ReadMultiple(filterArray.ToArray(), null, 100);
```

Comment: What if I want to fetch the data first and then filter the rows?

Comment: Dunno, never worked with datagrids. But as ReadMultiple returns array you can probably query it with LINQ like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332103/query-an-object-array-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

In other way, while publishing the page you can set the filter in page's SourceTableView property. This will gives only those fields which are follow the filter criteria.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. currently it is a comment not a full answer.