# Search array of a class c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a class that look like this

```
public class Bottle
{
    private string Brand = "";
    private string Beverage = "";
    private int Price =0;


    public Bottle(string _Brand, string _Beverage, int _Price)
    {
        Brand = _Brand;
        Beverage = _Beverage;
        Price =_Price; 
    }
}
```

Then i made an array of them:

```
 public Bottle[] Soda = new Bottle[25];
```

In a menu the user can chose to press 1, 2 or 3 to choose a soda to add. 
For example if they choose '1', they can then select a "place" in the array to store the soda. Like this:

```
Soda[userPlacement]= new Bottle("Cola","Soda",10);
```

My question is:

How do i Search that Array for Cola as example?

i've tried `Array.find`, and `Array.indexOf` but they didn't work.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332103/query-an-object-array-using-linq

Comment: It's easy using linq: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1175662/1997232) answer. Without linq basic idea is: iterate over array items (`for`, `foreach`) and check every item `Beverage` field value (you have to make it **public property** please). See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx) (underscore in parameter names is kek).

Comment: What code did you try that "didn't work"? Its likely you'd learn a lot more by having your  current attempt fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) like this:

```
Bottle cola = Soda.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Brand == "Cola");
```

This returns the first element in the array with `Brand` of `"Cola"` or `null` if there is none.

---

A simple straight forward version that also gives you the index could be this:

```
int colaIndex = -1;
for (int index = 0; index; index ++)
    if (Soda[index].Brand == "Cola")
    {
        colaIndex = index;
        break;
    }

if (colaIndex < 0)
    // no cola found
else
   // Soda[colaIndex] is your cola.
```

---

**Note**: as Sinatr correctly pointed out, you will need to make the `Brand` property `public` so it can be accessed by this code (alternatively you can put this code inside the `Bottle` class so it can access `private` fields).

Comment: Note: `Brand` is private field (unless code belong to member of `Bottle`).

Comment: Thank you @RenéVogt. Is it possible to sort the Array too? If so how?

Comment: @user6144256 yes you can sort it. There are `Sort` methods for arrays as well as `OrderBy` linq methods. You'll find a lot of threads about that on StackOverflow and the rest of the web. If they are not sufficient for you, open another question (it's too much for this thread, as I don't even know by _what_ you want to sort it).