# Blazor - Retrieve the data under the header of a specified JSON file

Tags: c#, json, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The `GetFromJsonAsync` method can be used to read data from a JSON file into a variable in a Blazor web application. The method works well for simple JSON files.

Example for `GetFromJsonAsync` method:

```cs
@code {
    private Students[]? students;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        students = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Students[]>("school.json");
    }

    public class Students
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public string? lastname { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My question is, how can I read only the data in a given JSON header?

Example:

```
{
  "book":[
     {
        "id":"444",
        "language":"C",
        "edition":"First",
        "author":"Dennis Ritchie "
     },
     {
        "id":"555",
        "language":"C++",
        "edition":"second",
        "author":" Bjarne Stroustrup "
     }
  ],
  "student": [ 
     { 
        "id":"01", 
        "name": "Tom", 
        "lastname": "Price" 
     }, 
     { 
        "id":"02", 
        "name": "Nick", 
        "lastname": "Thameson" 
     } 
  ]     
}
```

I only would like to read the data under the "student" JSON header into a `students` variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353470/search-array-of-a-class-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Root` class. And suggest naming the property names as Pascal case and using the `JsonPropertyName` attribute

```cs
public class Book
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("edition")]
    public string Edition { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("book")]
    public List<Book> Book { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("student")]
    public List<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the JSON as `Root` object.

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   Root root = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Root>("school.json");
   students = root.Students;
}
```