# Get specific columns who contains specific text

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an string array like this:

```
string[] tooltipstring
```

this array contain data like:

[image]

I want to know how can I select data depending of what text say.. for example I want to get only objects who have `progress to backcheck` then concat them and I should get:

```
- Median progress to backcheck = 0 minutes - Average progress to backcheck = 12 minutes
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Hi Rene.

Have a look at a similar question.

You can use Linq to query an array

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332103/query-an-object-array-using-linq

Comment: So should I need to create a separated model to achieve that I want? @OddmarDam

Comment: Check Aldert's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq and string.Join

```
using System.Linq;

string[] result = tooltipstring
                    .Where(tt => tt.Contains("progress to backcheck"))
                    .ToArray();

string finalResult = string.Join(" ", result);
```

Comment: nice! now I have 2 columns with progress to backcheck value, how can I union them into one string?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

string result = "- " + string.Join(" - ", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("progress to backcheck"));
```